# Images in listview changes as we scroll in android

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I am getting data from server. Data include images and text data. I want to show that data in my ListView . I have done this, but when ever i scroll the listview, images in the listview change their positions. how to fix this issue?

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertview == null) {
            convertview = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.rowImagview = (ImageView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_row_image);
            holder.Name_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_NameView);
            holder.Age_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_AgeView);
            holder.maritalStatus_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_MaaritalView);
            holder.Religion_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_Religion);
            holder.Profession_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_profession);
            holder.country_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_Country);
            holder.description_txtview = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_description_textView);
            holder.showDeatil_btn = (Button) convertview.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_pofDetail_btn);
            convertview.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
        }

        if (resultList.get(position).getUser_Gender().equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.loading).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.m_c1).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.m_c1).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
            maleImgPosition = 0;
        } else {
            options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.loading).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.f_c1).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.f_c1).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
            femaleImgPosition = 0;
        }

        /* Image Loader Library to get the images from the server */
        imageLoader.displayImage(Url_Settings.Image_base_Url + resultList.get(position).getUser_defaultImag(), holder.rowImagview, options, animateFirstListener);
```

Comment: just for testing cut the whole code from if (convertView == null) {} and paste outside it then comment out if (convertView == null) {} else {holder = (ViewHolder) convertview.getTag();} part and run.Check what happens?

Answer (score 0):

The problem why this happens is because android reuses cells for list view when they are no longer visible for the new rows being displayed (when scrolling with down-to-up gesture top most items are used to show new coming bottom ones). As downloa operation is time expensive the displayImage sets the image with delay - at that point of time user may scroll down and android already uses passed holder.rowImagview for different row (it was top most when download was requested and reused as bottom view after scroll when download finised).

To avoid that you should use displayImage with callback so you have more control of setting image and decide if the image should be set in this particular rowImageView instance

So you can do it like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    final ImageView rowImageView = holder.rowImageView;
    rowImagview.setTag(position);

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, rowImagview, displayOptions, new SimpleImageLoadingListener()      {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            ImageView rowImageView = (ImageView)rowImageView;
            if(((Integer)rowImageView.getTag()) == position){
                //the row is still correct, set bitmap
                rowImageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
            }
        ...
        }
    }
    });
....
}
```

You can also check by imageUri parameter and set the image only if one came from onLoadingComplete() is the same as for current row.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertview, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_result_row, null);

        ImageView rowImagview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_row_image);
        TextView Name_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_NameView);
        TextView Age_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_AgeView);
        TextView maritalStatus_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_MaaritalView);
        TextView Religion_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_Religion);
        TextView Profession_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_profession);
        TextView country_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_Country);
        TextView description_txtview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_description_textView);
        Button showDeatil_btn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.Srch_result_pofDetail_btn);


    if (resultList.get(position).getUser_Gender().equalsIgnoreCase("male")) {
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.loading).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.m_c1).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.m_c1).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
        maleImgPosition = 0;
    } else {
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showStubImage(R.drawable.loading).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.f_c1).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.f_c1).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20)).build();
        femaleImgPosition = 0;
    }

    /* Image Loader Library to get the images from the server */
    imageLoader.displayImage(Url_Settings.Image_base_Url + resultList.get(position).getUser_defaultImag(), rowImagview, options, animateFirstListener);

    return v;
    }
```